# Not able to open downloaded Excel file from Sharepoint 2013 using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, xmlhttprequest, adodb

i have tried the following code to download a single Excel file from Sharepoint 2013.

Option Explicit

```
Sub TxtStream()

Dim myURL As String, DestFile As String, myHeader As String
Dim Usr as string, Pwd as string
Dim oStream As Object

Usr="": Pwd=""

myURL = "https://Server.Name/teams/Forms/AllItems.aspx/MasterFile.xlsx"
DestFile = "C:\Test.xlsx"

Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

'WinHttpReq.Open "HEAD", myURL, False, Usr, Pwd
'WinHttpReq.Send
'myHeader = WinHttpReq.getAllResponseHeaders()
'Debug.Print myHeader
'myHeader = WinHttpReq.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition")
'Debug.Print myHeader
'myHeader = WinHttpReq.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")
'Debug.Print myHeader

WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False, Usr, Pwd
WinHttpReq.setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/octet-stream"
WinHttpReq.Send

myURL = WinHttpReq.responsebody

If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Position = 0
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responsebody
    oStream.SaveToFile DestFile, 2
    oStream.Close
End If

End Sub
```

It downloads ok, but when i try to open it in Excel 2010, it shoots an error:

> Excel cannot open the file Test.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file.

I have checked the Content-Type and it shows as Text/Html;UTF-8. It doesn't show Content-Disposition.

Can someone help as to why the file is not opening?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full fledged answer, but more like a comment / suggestion as I do not have enough reputation to post comments.

Setting a content-type header in your GET query does not seems to make any difference. We need to check the `WinHttpReq.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")` sent by the server which in this case seems to be Text/Html;UTF-8.

If you copy paste the URL used in myURL variable to your browser, do you get the "file save as" dialog box?

Better analysis of your requests and responses can be done if you use [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) where you can create requests in teh composer and check the responses to finetune your requirements and to see whether any other headers (like cookies, authentications etc) are also required for the file to be downloaded. In this case, you might be getting back a login page (html) because of some authentication issues and not the excel file.

Open the DestFile saved with Notepad.exe to see whether it is actualy an XLSX file (starting with characters PK) or an HTML or other text file.